# Two types of averages for ratios of two things

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

It was brought to my attention in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czsY8z2SOro) video that, where you have some attribute of your data that is the ratio of two other attributes, there are two ways of generating the mean "average" of this ratio.

Taking the example from the beginning of the video, suppose that $x_i$ is the total sales (in \$) for a given line item, and $k_i$ is the quantity sold:

| Item ID | Sales | Qty sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accessory #1 | $x_1$ | $k_1$ |
| Accessory #2 | $x_2$ | $k_2$ |
| Accessory #3 | $x_3$ | $k_3$ |

For each individual line item, you might define "Sales per unit" as $u_i=\frac{x_i}{k_i}$. However, as the video points out, there are two ways one might then define the average Sales per unit for an Accessory. Using the video's terminology:

$$\text{AGG}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{k_1+k_2+k_3}$$

$$\text{AVG}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x_1}{k_1}+\frac{x_2}{k_2}+\frac{x_3}{k_3}\right)$$

So $\text{AVG}$ is just $\bar{u}$, whereas $\text{AGG}$ creates a composite Accessory item $\left(X, K\right)$, whose sales and quantity are the sum of the individual line items', and calculates $U=\frac{X}{K}$ for that composite item.

Plugging in example numbers for the $x_i$ and $k_i$ suggests that $\text{AGG}$ and $\text{AVG}$ do not in general give the same value. My question is: what are the qualitative differences in what $\text{AGG}$ and $\text{AVG}$ are doing? Which provides the better view of what average sales per unit for an Accessory are?

Comment: Well, scale has more of an impact on one than the other.  If, say, $(x_1,k_1)$ are in the billions while the others are all single digits, then $(x_1,k_1)$ dominates the first average, but not the second.

Comment: As a side note (not implying any particular answer to the question), if the same accessory sometimes sells for a different price -- that is, if $x_1$ cannot simply be derived from $x_1 = p_1 k_1$ where $p_1$ is the known constant price of the accessory -- then $x_1/k_1$ is already an "AGG" kind of average price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple average $$\text{AVG}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x_1}{k_1}+\frac{x_2}{k_2}+\frac{x_3}{k_3}\right)$$ is the **mean selling price of the three types of accessories**, whereas the [weighted average](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4398869/21813) $$\text{AGG}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{k_1+k_2+k_3}$$ is the **mean selling price of the units of accessories**, accounting for the unequal sales volumes among the three types.

Answer (score 2):

AGG gives a weighted average, so that if a particular accessory (e.g. Accessory #1) is outselling all of the other accessories combined, then more weight is given to the ratio of $u_1 = \frac{x_1}{k_1}.$

The research is targeting the generic customer who comes into the store to buy $n$ items, where there is a narrow range between the **typical** maximum and minimum values of $n$.  The store wants to know (in general) what the profit from that person will be.  This can be useful when there is little variance between the ratio of how many items of accessory $i$ were sold versus how many items of accessory $j$.

There is a presumption here that the store can predict its overall gross sales by the amount of foot traffic inside the store.  A 24 hour store might use such research to consider whether to have the store closed between $12$ midnight and $6$ am.

AVG presumes that it is irrelevant what the nature of the accessories are, or which accessories sell the most.  The idea is that AVG is geared to a customer who only wants to spend a certain dollar range per item, **no matter** what he buys.  So, AVG, charts typical price per accessory, giving equal weight among accessories, regardless of whether one accessory outsells another.